# Climbing a ladder with a character controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an empty object that contains a number of cubes resulting in a ladder. With the help of debugging I ended up adding a rigidbody to each relevant cube and turned both 'Is Kinematic' and 'Is Trigger' on. I adjusted the box collider boundaries and I have this for my trigger:

```
// Trigger inside my player movement script
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // Collider name equals Ladder
        if (other.tag == "Ladder")
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log("Player is climbing.");
        }
    }
```

I tried using my controller.move aswell, but that resulted in no results at all coming back from my debugging. I used an if statement to determine if player 'isClimbing' and using an input, but climbing was still not possible. I believe I am missing flags but I can't figure out what else is required.

Comment: Have you checked if the method is called? And if it is the tag that is not set up properly?

Comment: Yeah I have all that setup. I have my ladder and all children of that gameObject as 'Ladder' tag, and I now have an isClimbing if statement which has the vector3.up. Still nothing so far